# What apache config is causing domain.com/index.php/abcdefg to work when there is no such file?

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, configuration

I have a page :

```
http://domain.com/index.php
```

But strangely, the following `urls` are also working and rendering the same page :

```
http://domain.com/index.php/abcd
http://domain.com/index.php/gefe
```

and so on..

Clearly, it seems to be a screwed up `regex` config. But strangely, the urls continue to work even when I deleted my `.htaccess` file.

Now, I can only blame my `apache` config for this but everything seems as expected.

My apache config :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Server name
    ServerName domain.com
    # Document root
    DocumentRoot /path/to/source

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
    <Directory /path/to/source>
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel error

    # Logs
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_access.log combined

    RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone point out the mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called PATH_INFO. Apache will scan a URL from left-to-right. As long as it finds directories that match, it'll keep doing down the document root, until it either runs out of directories, or hits a script that matches. After that, any extra "path" information becomes PATH_INFO, e.g.

you have a site with a script called 'foo.php' in a really-does-exist dir structure of /a/b/c, so that

```
http://example.com/a/b/c/foo.php
```

is a valid url.

IN that case,

```
http://example.com/a/b/c/foo.php/bar/baz/bip/bop/boop
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- path info
```

Read up: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo

Comment: can I stop it from happening ? Somehow, google is indexing the weird urls. I need to atleast give them a 301.

Comment: Read the linked doc. turning off `AcceptPathInfo` will force Apache to treat the path info as regular directories, and it'll return a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to a URL like that is perfectly legitimate - the extra path is available to your PHP code in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

It's not that different to saying `http://domain.com/index.php?ab=cd`, just a different way to add further information to a URL.